# add elements to validate function conditionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I've created a simple form and validated it using `jquery validation`

```
$('#form').validate({
    errorClass: 'error-field error', 
    // and some more elements....
});
```

I want to add a `validClass` to this form validation if a specific condition is held, for example:

```
if ( someCondition ){
    $('#form').validate({validClass: 'valid-field'});
}
```

But this does not work and it seems the `.validate()` function should be only called once, so what should I do with this situation!?

Thanks!

Comment: so when is this condition checked...

Comment: after calling the .validate() method

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1g6nn2h7/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved by a little trick:

```
$('#form').validate({
    errorClass: 'error-field error', 
    validClass: condition ? 'valid-field' : null
});
```